# Possible to travel between worlds in SMP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As seen in Creative mode, you could travel between different worlds or maps. I was wondering if such would be possible on SMP. I currently run Hey0.

Comment: Nether is not possible at the moment (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11107/how-does-the-nether-work-in-minecraft-smp) and there are no server commands as far as I know for changing maps. However, restarting your server to load a different map isn't the worst thing if you announce it to everyone in-game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely planned, but not yet implemented as of right now. (This may change with the upcoming beta release, although I doubt it.)

As a matter of fact, portals to Nether are very likely to actually run in a separate server instances to be connected via this "travel" system.

Comment: Which, I believe Notch stated, was the origin of portals to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you run Hey0, theres a plugin that can do that.
http://www.google.com/search?q=hey0+forum+server+redirect

Comment: No, since this is for travelling between servers, not worlds. I would actually have to run two Hey0s on different ports. That is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Portals to the Nether have now been implemented.  Just set `allownether=true` in your `server.properties` file (IIRC, it's set that way by default).  You do not need to start a second server.

Comment: however, SMP in 1.6.5 has some serious issues but notch [said "I’ll fix those next week"](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/5938461844/minecraft-beta-1-6-5)

Comment: @Tobias I keep hearing that but I haven't seen any serious bugs. what are they?

Comment: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Version_history

Comment: @TobiasKienzler whoa that's some bug list!  I guess I just got lucky!